Missing biography of Herbert Becker
When Herbert Becker and Walther Bothe directed alpha particles (helium nuclei) at beryllium in 1930, a strong, penetrating radiation was emitted. This radiation later led to the discovery of neutrons in 1932 by Chadwick.
While the biographies of Walther Bothe and Chadwick are available on Wikipedia, a biography of Herbert Becker appears to be missing from the internet. Can someone please point to an online resource to get a biography of Herbert Becker, especially the year and place of his birth and death?

Paywalled, I have no access: W. Bothe and H. Becker, "Künstliche Erregung von Kern-γ-Strahlen." Zeitschrift für Physik, Vol. 66, No. 5-6, May 1930, pp. 289-306. H. Becker and W. Bothe, "Die in Bor und Beryllium erregten γ-Strahlen." Zeitschrift für Physik, Vol. 76, No. 7-8, Jul. 1932, pp. 421-438. In 1930 Becker is listed as "Dr. Herbert Becker, Physikalisch-Technische Reichsanstalt, Berlin-Charlottenburg". I have been unable to find his Ph.D. dissertation. Unfortunately, Herbert Becker is a fairly common name. Dissertations commonly included a mini-biography at that time.

Becker, Herbert appears in a list of PhD titles conferred by Friedrich-Wilhelms-Universität zu Berlin between Dec. 4, 1929 and Mar. 6, 1930.

@njuffa Thanks for the pointers. However, shelling out 40 € for an article is not an option, especially when there is no guarantee it contains the information I seek.
